# Azure Storage account static website custom domain without www

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cdn, azure-storage-account

I've got my React app running on azure Storage account static website (frontend only). I've bought a domain and attached it to static website following this instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name
All great - I've managed to access the website using www.*mydomain.com*
However, the issue is that looks like to be able to access it without the www bit I'll have to use Azure CDN which looks pretty pricey.
Does anyone know if there is a way to access my domain without www without using Azure CDN?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can **map the Azure storage account’s static website created with the custom domain through the public DNS zone created in Azure and accordingly creating a ‘CNAME’ record for it in the DNS zone. Once, you create a ‘CNAME’ record for the static website’s custom domain mapped with any other hostname or DNS record other than ‘www’, you will be able to access the website with that DNS record/FQDN or IP address mapped along with it**.

•   Please find the below snapshots given for the configuration done regarding the above. Accordingly, I have **deployed the static website in the storage account and enabled the CDN in it too. Then, I deployed a DNS zone for the custom domain name in which I created a ‘CNAME’ host record for the static website’s created endpoint URL and tried to access it and it was successful. I also ensured that the DNS record created was not ‘www’***.

[image: Azure CDN]
[image: Azure CDN Endpoint]
[image: Azure CDN hostname mapping]
[image: Azure CDN custom domain name mapping]

Please find the below link for more detailed information regarding the above configuration: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup***